# ggplot: add mean value to a stacked barplot (secondary axis)

Tags: r, ggplot2

1. I am dealing with survey data and now I am trying to add text-labels to a stacked bar plot. What am I doing wrong?

```r
# Sample Data
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(item = sample(paste("Item", 1:4), size=n, replace=TRUE),
                 value = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE))


# Create stacked barplot
df %>% group_by(item) %>%
  count(value) %>%
  mutate(percent = 1 / sum(n) * n,
         answer = factor(value, ordered=TRUE)) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = percent, fill = fct_rev(answer))) + 
    geom_col() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    geom_text(aes(label = round(percent, 1))) +
    labs(fill = "Answer")
```

2. I am supposed to add additional mean values for every item. Is there a way to add a secondary axis ranging from 1 to 5 and add the mean values for each item as points to the plot? (even though I know, that statistically this is somewhat questionable as 100% does not really correspond to the maximum value of 5)

Comment: For the second part of your question, I don't think what you're asking is feasible (or maybe I've misunderstood). Are you able to please edit your question to add some more details? E.g. could you take the existing figure and 'draw' the extra axis on how you want it to look?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the position of the labels; at the moment your code places them at their respective positions (i.e. 0.2 is placed at 0.2 on the y axis, and 0.3 is placed at 0.3 on the y axis), but if you add `position = position_stack()` this should solve your first problem, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
n <- 100
df <- data.frame(item = sample(paste("Item", 1:4), size=n, replace=TRUE),
                 value = sample(1:5, size=n, replace=TRUE))


# Create stacked barplot
df %>% group_by(item) %>%
  count(value) %>%
  mutate(percent = 1 / sum(n) * n,
         answer = factor(value, ordered=TRUE)) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = percent, fill = fct_rev(answer))) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(percent, 1)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  labs(fill = "Answer")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>